# Python Testing without sql connection

Tags: python, sql, testing

- I am using sql to pull in values from 'lookup' table. I will use
  cursor and fetchall and then loop through values and place them into
  dictionary. I do not see reason to keep querying database(open conn,
  query, close conn) for every lookup performed when a dictionary of
  subset of data should suffice. Is this 'standard' practice to use dictionary in-lieu of table ?
- Is there  a way to test this with different sets of values without connecting to database? I would prefer at least unit testing without connecting to data store. Some framework or some pattern? Not sure what to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of this. And although it sounds like a cop out, the answer is "it depends":
If the dataset is very large I would keep referring back to the database as loading it in to memory could be a resource issue.
If the dataset is not to large then loading it in to a memory and referring to it can really improve performance.

I tend to test and see what the performance is like.